# Change values of multiple pixels in a RGB image

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, rgb

I have to change pixel values in a RGB image.
I have two arrays indicating positions, so:

```
rows_to_change = [r1, r2, r3, ..., rn];
columns_to_change = [c1, c2, c3, ..., cn];
```

I would operate this modification without loops. So intuitively, in order to set the red color in those location, I write:

```
image(rows_to_change, columns_to_change, :) = [255, 0, 0];
```

This code line returns an error.

How can I operate this change without using a double for loop?

Comment: Does `image(rows_to_change, columns_to_change, :)` index all pixels you want? This way you also index pixels like (r1,c2,:), is this intended?

Comment: I would that `image(r1,c1,:)=[255, 0, 0]`; `image(r2,c2,:)=[255, 0, 0]`; until `image(rn,cn,:)=[255, 0, 0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sub2ind` for this, but it's easier to work per channel:

```
red = image(:,:,1);
green = image(:,:,2);    
blue = image(:,:,3);
```

Convert your row and column indices (i.e. subscript indices) to linear indices (per 2D channel):

```
idx = sub2ind(size(red),rows_to_change,columns_to_change)
```

Set the colours per channel:

```
red(idx) = 255;
green(idx) = 0;
blue(idx) = 0;
```

Concatenate the channels to form a colour image:

```
new_image = cat(3,red,green,blue)
```

Comment: No way without separate channels?

Comment: @Alessandro it would be a mess, but probably using `permute`. However, you have a finite (and very small) and fixed number of channels so separating them is a good option. If you need to do this many times, just wrap it up in a function.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to separate the channels you can us this code, but it's definitely more complicated to do it this way:

```
%your pixel value
rgb=[255, 0, 0]
%create a 2d mask which is true where you want to change the pixel
mask=false(size(image,1),size(image,2))
mask(sub2ind(size(image),rows_to_change,columns_to_change))=1
%extend it to 3d
mask=repmat(mask,[1,1,size(image,3)])
%assign the values based on the mask.
image(mask)=repmat(rgb(:).',numel(rows_to_change),1)
```

The primary reason I originally came up with this idea where Images with a variable number of channels.

Comment: I will try this option. Effectively it seem more complicated respect of separating three channels.