# How to change pixel values of an RGB image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

So what I need to do is to apply an operation like

```
(x(i,j)-min(x)) / max(x(i,j)-min(x))
```

which basically converts each pixel value such that the values range between 0 and 1.

First of all, I realised that Matlab saves our image(rows * col * colour) in a 3D matrix on using imread,

```
Image = imread('image.jpg')
```

So, a simple max operation on image doesn't give me the max value of pixel and I'm not quite sure what it returns(another multidimensional array?). So I tried using something like

```
max_pixel = max(max(max(Image)))
```

I thought it worked fine. Similarly I used min thrice. My logic was that I was getting the min pixel value across all 3 colour planes.

After performing the above scaling operation I got an image which seemed to have only 0 or 1 values and no value in between which doesn't seem right. Has it got something to do with integer/float rounding off?

```
image = imread('cat.jpg')
maxI = max(max(max(image)))
minI = min(min(min(image)))
new_image = ((I-minI)./max(I-minI))
```

This gives output of only 1s and 0s which doesn't seem correct.

The other approach I'm trying is working on all colour planes separately as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434119/change-values-of-multiple-pixels-in-a-rgb-image). But is that the correct way to do it?

I could also loop through all pixels but I'm assuming that will be time taking. Very new to this, any help will be great.

Comment: It's unclear without an example, but seems like you want to use the `dim` argument to `max`/`min`, as described in the docs. Also I think the bottom of the fraction in your first equation should be (max(x)-min(x)), taking the max of (x-min(x)) will not normalise the data between 0 and 1.

Comment: @wolfie x(i,j)-min(x) will make the value of minimum pixel 0, and all others will have some value, say max of which is y, now dividing with max(x(i,j)-min(x)) means dividing with y so the max value of pixel becomes 1. Isn't it?  And what kind of example should I provide? Do you mean the code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is your image generated? If its RGB already, then its not a "data matrix", its a color representation of something. This means that its either 0-255, 0-1, or possibly wrongly generated.

Comment: @AnderBiguri so I read the image using imread..it gives output with values ranging from `0-255`. also `size(image)` gives `375   500     3`, which means it's RGB I think. When I use `red = image(:,:,1)` and then `size(red)` I get `375   500`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure what a matlab functions returns or why, you should always do one of the following first:

Type `help >functionName<` or `doc >functionName<` in the command window, in your case: `doc max`. This will show you the essential must-know information of that specific function, such as what needs to be put in, and what will be output.

In the case of the `max` function, this yields the following results:

> M = max(A) returns the maximum elements of an array.
>
> If A is a vector, then max(A) returns the maximum of A.
>
> If A is a matrix, then max(A) is a row vector containing the maximum
>   value of each column.
>
> If A is a multidimensional array, then max(A) operates along the first
>   array dimension whose size does not equal 1, treating the elements as
>   vectors. The size of this dimension becomes 1 while the sizes of all
>   other dimensions remain the same. If A is an empty array whose first
>   dimension has zero length, then max(A) returns an empty array with the
>   same size as A

In other words, if you use `max()` on a matrix, it will output a vector that contains the maximum value of each column (the first non-singleton dimension). If you use `max()` on a matrix `A` of size `m x n x 3`, it will result in a matrix of maximum values of size `1 x n x 3`. So this answers your question:

> I'm not quite sure what it returns(another multidimensional array?)

Moving on:

> I thought it worked fine. Similarly I used min thrice. My logic was that I was getting the min pixel value across all 3 colour planes.

This is correct. Alternatively, you can use `max(A(:))` and `min(A(:))`, which is equivalent if you are just looking for the value.

> And after performing the above operation I got an image which seemed to have only 0 or 1 values and no value in between which doesn't seem right. Has it got something to do with integer/float rounding off?

There is no way for us to know why this happens if you do not post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. It could be that it is because your variables are of a certain type, or it could be because of an error in your calculations.

> The other approach I'm trying is working on all colour planes separately as done here. But is that the correct way to do it?

This depends on what the intended end result is. Normalizing each colour (red, green, blue) seperately will result in a different result as compared to normalizing the values all at once (in 99% of cases, anyway).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I've read the help section number of times. The part about multidimensional arrays wasn't very clear to me, even now. I'll try writing the code in a script and add it here so I can be more clear.

Comment: I don't blame you, especially when you are just getting into matlab the wording can be a bit convolved sometimes. I do strongly recommend playing around with the optional `dim` argument that Wolfie mentioned. Not only does it occur in many more matlab functions (`sum`,`mean`,`rms`, to name a few), it is also incredibly useful.

Comment: `max(A(:))` is equivalent in that it produces the sand output. But it is much more efficient!

Comment: True that, Cris! :^)

Answer (score 1):

You have a `uint8` RGB image.

Just convert it to a double image by

```
I=imread('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0b/Cat_poster_1.jpg/1920px-Cat_poster_1.jpg')

I=double(I)./255;
```

alternatively

```
I=im2double(I); %does the scaling if needed
```

[Read about image data types](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html)

---

## What are you doing wrong?

If what you want todo is convert a RGB image to [0-1] range, you are approaching the problem badly, regardless of the correctness of your MATLAB code. Let me give you an example of why:

Say you have an image with 2 colors.

A dark red (20,0,0): [image]

A medium blue (0,0,128) [image]

Now you want this changed to [0-1]. How do you scale it? Your suggested approach is to make the value `128->1` and either `20->20/128` or `20->1` (not relevant). However when you do this, you are changing the color! you are making the medium blue to be intense blue (maximum B channel, [image]) and making R way way more intense (instead of 20/255, 20/128, double brightness! [image]). This is bad, as this is with simple colors, but with combined RGB values you may even change the color itsef, not only the intensity. Therefore, the only correct way to convert to [0-1] range is to assume your min and max are [0, 255].

Comment: I've added some code in the question. I also tried to use `I=double(I)` after reading the image and then repeated the steps however the line `new_city = ((I-min_pixel)./max(I-min_pixel))` no longer runs. It gives the error `Error using  - 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.`

Comment: @momo the code here is *instead* of what you are trying to do not  *together* with it. I showed you how to normalize an image between 0-1. What you are triying to do will mess the colors (unless you have a RGB that is [0,0,0] and anther one that is [255,255,255], but you can not ensure 100% this).

Comment: ah.. I figured `I=im2double(I)` does the scaling , but I thought `I=double(I)` might help me with the 0 and 1 issue. I can't use im2double because I'm trying to figure the working manually actually. But still thanks a lot.

Comment: ah!! silly silly mistake.. I used the wrong variables `min_pixel` instead of `minI`. It seems `I=double(I)` did work and values are now ranging from 0 to 1. I'll try the next part and see if things work.

Comment: @momo I added an explanation of why your approach is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: What if I multiplied the new resultant image with 255 now. Will that be fine? Say my goal is to increase the contrast. Won't I be achieving that?